# User input used as a parameter in a function c++

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing

While I understand why my code is wrong as well as brute-forcing my way around it, I'm wondering if there is way to do it the way I imagined it, so: 
(just for context I'm making a simple game called Tower of Hanoi and this is the function I made that works when I manually input my stack as parameters)

```
void putOn(std::stack<int> &first, std::stack<int> &second){
    if(first.empty()){
        std::cout << "Your stack is empty, try again";
    }else if(first.top() && second.empty()){
        second.push(first.top());
        first.pop();
    }else if(first.top() < second.top()){
        second.push(first.top());
        first.pop();
    }else if(first.top() > second.top()){
        std::cout << "You can only put larger pieces on top." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Later in my code I'm using switch-case(for input, move towers, etc.) What I'm trying to do is translate my line `putOn(x,y)` into a variable input like so:

```
            case 1:
                char a,b;
                std::cout << "Enter the tower u want to move from(x, y, z): ";
                std::cin >> a;
                std::cout << std::endl;
                std::cout << "To(x, y, z): ";
                std::cin >> b;
                std::cout << std::endl;
//              putOn(&a,&b);
//              putOn(a,b);
                break;
```

You can tell where I'm going with this and obviously I get get an error that says: `candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char *' to 'std::stack<int> &' for 1st argument void putOn(std::stack<int> &first, std::stack<int> &second){`
Is there a "python-like" way to do this where my user input directly translates character variables `a` and `b` into `x,y` or `z` as parameters, thank you for your time

Comment: You have to validate the input, ensure it's 1, 2 or 3. Or a,b, or c. You then map those to the 3 stacks you have. You can use `a - '1'` or `a - 'a'` to compute an index into an array of 3 stacks *after* validating the input a. Don't forget to test for a != b. Can't move from/to the same stack.

Comment: Actually stack are pre-declared and they're always `std::stack<int> x; std::stack<int> y; std::stack<int> z;`, so that's why user chooses between x, y or z, my original idea to go about it was `if(a == 'x' && b == 'x') putOn(x,y);` and so on.. so there has to be a faster way to do this, but I don't know how

Comment: auto pick = [=](char a) switch(a) { case 'x': return x; case 'y': return y; case 'z': return z; default: throw std::invalid_argument("Stack does not exist"); }   std::stack<int> &from = pick(a); std::stack<int> &to = pick<b>; (not syntax checked)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
std::map<char, std::stack<int>*> m = {{'x', &x}, {'y', &y}, {'z', &z}};
//...
putOn(*m[a], *m[b]);
```

Comment: Beware: what happens with your current putOn() Implementation when the user enters the same tower twice?

Comment: Absolutely nothing, my program works as is, and we have 0 requirements for our assignment but this just looks so ugly that it pisses me off so I wanted to fix that: `if(a == 'x' && b == 'y'){putOn(x,y);} ... if(a == 'z' && b == 'y'){putOn(z,y);}
`also I tried your map thingy, it just spits out a ton of errors, mainly: `use of undeclared identifier 'm`, `no template named 'map' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'max'?`, `error: called object type 'std::stack<int> *' is not a function or function pointer` there's also a warning saying that expression result is being unused

Comment: `#include <map>` ... generally, this page tells you which header to include, at the top: cppreference.com

Comment: `error: non-aggregate type 'std::map<char, std::stack<int> *>' cannot be initialized with an initializer list`, `error: cannot jump from switch statement to this case label case 3: note: jump bypasses variable initialization` I get the first error both when initializating globaly and inside of the switch-case, but when inside switch case, I get another error with bypassing that initialization

Comment: Also it's completely fine, there's no need for you to debug my program, I can look into map function myself and figure it out, thanks for throwing the idea out for me, it's more than enough, judging by the upvotes, I'm sure I'll make it work somehow